# Full screen white navbar underline? HTML/css

Tags: html, css, navigation, underline

I would like to replicate the underline like in this example:

[image]

I was just going to use a basic coloured underline, but I can't get is as thin, or positioned perfectly under the nav' bar, what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `Border-Bottom`

Comment: Ahh, yes that looks like it would work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `border-bottom` for this. Here is an example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Turns out the CSS framework I'm using has a Horizontal line, which works! As a note it's <hr> in Turret.